# how to assign all objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, javascript-objects

lets say I have an array like this:

```
[ { full_name: 'Sickö' }, 
  { location: 'New York City, United States' },
  { follower: '1.2M' },
  { er: '5.59%' },
  { topics: 'Fashion' } ]
```

and I want to make it as an object like:

```
{
  fullname: 'Sicko',
  location: 'New York City, United State'
  ..and more
}
```

I'm aware that I can combine them using `Object.assign` but no idea how I can assign all of them.

Comment: How do you know when to move onto another object as the array in your example appears have an object designated for each property of the object you want to create.

Answer (score 4):

```
let all = [ { full_name: 'Sickö' }, 
  { location: 'New York City, United States' },
  { follower: '1.2M' },
  { er: '5.59%' },
  { topics: 'Fashion' } ];

let res = Object.assign({}, ...all);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) starting with an accumulator equal to the empty object `{}` and use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) on each iteration of the reducer. Something like this:

```js
const input = [
  {full_name: 'Sickö'},
  {location: 'New York City, United States'},
  {follower: '1.2M'},
  {er: '5.59%'},
  {topics: 'Fashion'}
];

function assign(acc, obj)
{
    return Object.assign(acc, obj);
}

let res = input.reduce(assign, {});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, `Object.assign()` is designed to accept multiple `sources`, so you can just use it with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) if you have `ES6` support:

```js
const input = [
  {full_name: 'Sickö'},
  {location: 'New York City, United States'},
  {follower: '1.2M'},
  {er: '5.59%'},
  {topics: 'Fashion'}
];

let res = Object.assign({}, ...input);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: How does this work when their are multiple objects in the array ie, not every single object is to be part of one single object?

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged jquery, incase you need a solution using the same:

```js
var data = [ { full_name: 'Sickö' }, 
  { location: 'New York City, United States' },
  { follower: '1.2M' },
  { er: '5.59%' },
  { topics: 'Fashion' } ];

var d = $.extend({}, ...data);

console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```